# Map markers are throwing error while clicking in Android

Tags: android, android-mapview, android-maps

I am making an app which shows google map with 5 connected coordinates. I am able to mark them with an icon. Now i am trying to show a dialog when we click on those markers but i am getting error. Please find the code as below. Any help would be much appreciated.

This is my Main class.

```
public class MapConnect extends MapActivity implements LocationListener { 

    private static final String TAG = "LocationActivity";
//  public List<Overlay> mapOverlays;
//  public MyOwnLocationOverlay myLocationOverlay;
    public static MapConnect instance;
    public MapView mapView; 
    protected LocationManager locationManager;
    public Button retrieveLocationButton;
    Geocoder geocoder; 
    TextView locationText;
    Location location;
    MapController mapController;
    CountDownTimer locationtimer;
    GeoPoint point1 = new GeoPoint(29391748,13436279);
    GeoPoint point2 = new GeoPoint(28835050,14128418);
    GeoPoint point3 = new GeoPoint(28256006,13941650);
    GeoPoint point4 = new GeoPoint(28401065,13029785);
    GeoPoint point5 = new GeoPoint(29027355,12546387);

        //  private static final long MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 1; // in Meters
//  private static final long MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES = 9000; // in Milliseconds
//    MapOverlay mapOverlay = new MapOverlay();
    @Override        
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_map_connect);

        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map_view);

        MyLocationOverlay myLocationOverlay = new MyLocationOverlay(this, mapView);
        mapView.getOverlays().add(myLocationOverlay);
        mapView.postInvalidate();
        myLocationOverlay.enableMyLocation();
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        locationText = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.lblLocationInfo);
        mapController = mapView.getController(); 
        mapView.setSatellite(false);
        mapController.setZoom(8);
        retrieveLocationButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.retrieve_location_button);

//        GeoPoint point1 = new GeoPoint(29391748,13436279);
//        GeoPoint point2 = new GeoPoint(28835050,14128418);
//        GeoPoint point3 = new GeoPoint(28256006,13941650);
//        GeoPoint point4 = new GeoPoint(28401065,13029785);
//        GeoPoint point5 = new GeoPoint(29027355,12546387);
          MapOverlay mapOvlay = new MapOverlay(point1, point2,point3,point4,point5);
          //mapController.setCenter(point4);
          mapView.getOverlays().add(mapOvlay);

          List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
          Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pin);
          HelloItemizedOverlay itemizedoverlay = new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawable);
          OverlayItem overlayitem  = new OverlayItem(point1, null, null);
          OverlayItem overlayitem1 = new OverlayItem(point2, null, null);
          OverlayItem overlayitem2 = new OverlayItem(point3, null, null);
          OverlayItem overlayitem3 = new OverlayItem(point4, null, null);
          OverlayItem overlayitem4 = new OverlayItem(point5, null, null);
          itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
          itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem1);
          itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem2);
          itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem3);
          itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem4);
          mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);


    }

    public class MapOverlay extends com.google.android.maps.Overlay {

        private GeoPoint mGpt1;
        private GeoPoint mGpt2;
        private GeoPoint mGpt3;
        private GeoPoint mGpt4;
        private GeoPoint mGpt5;

        protected MapOverlay(GeoPoint gp1, GeoPoint gp2,GeoPoint gp3,GeoPoint gp4,GeoPoint gp5 ) {
           mGpt1 = gp1;
           mGpt2 = gp2;
           mGpt3 = gp3;
           mGpt4 = gp4;
           mGpt5 = gp5;
           mapController.setCenter(gp3);
        }
        @Override
        public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow,
              long when) {
           super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);
           Paint paint;
           paint = new Paint();
           paint.setColor(Color.RED);
           paint.setAntiAlias(true);
           paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
           paint.setStrokeWidth(2);
           Point pt1 = new Point();
           Point pt2 = new Point();
           Point pt3 = new Point();
           Point pt4 = new Point();
           Point pt5 = new Point();
           Projection projection = mapView.getProjection();
           projection.toPixels(mGpt1, pt1);
           projection.toPixels(mGpt2, pt2);
           projection.toPixels(mGpt3, pt3);
           projection.toPixels(mGpt4, pt4);
           projection.toPixels(mGpt5, pt5);
           canvas.drawLine(pt1.x, pt1.y, pt2.x, pt2.y, paint);
           canvas.drawLine(pt2.x, pt2.y, pt3.x, pt3.y, paint);
           canvas.drawLine(pt3.x, pt3.y, pt4.x, pt4.y, paint);
           canvas.drawLine(pt4.x, pt4.y, pt5.x, pt5.y, paint);
           canvas.drawLine(pt5.x, pt5.y, pt1.x, pt1.y, paint);
           return true;
        }

     }


//       public void drawMyLocation(Canvas canvas,MapView mapView,location,point,Long 1000);

       public void showsat(View view){
        mapView.setSatellite(true);
       }

       public void showcurrentlocation(View view) {

//      mapView.getOverlays().clear(); 
//      mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
//      
//      myLocationOverlay = new MyOwnLocationOverlay(GMapsActivity.this, mapView);  
//      myLocationOverlay.setMeters(10);      
//      myLocationOverlay.enableCompass();        
//      myLocationOverlay.enableMyLocation();        
//      myLocationOverlay.runOnFirstFix(new Runnable() {    
//          public void run() {              
//              mapController.animateTo(myLocationOverlay.getMyLocation());    
//              }       
//          });      
//      mapView.getOverlays().add(myLocationOverlay);   }
        mapView.setSatellite(false);        
        geocoder = new Geocoder(MapConnect.this);
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        // add this overlay to the MapView and refresh it


        if (location != null) {     
            Log.d(TAG, location.toString());   
            this.onLocationChanged(location); //<6>  

            } 

        }
//    
       @Override
       public void onBackPressed() {
           // do something on back.
           MapOverlay mapOvlay = new MapOverlay(point1, point2,point3,point4,point5);
           mapView.getOverlays().add(mapOvlay);
          // finish();
           return;
       }    
       public void finish() {
           // do something on back.
           finish();
           return;
       }        

    @Override  
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onLocationChanged with location " + location.toString());   
            String text = String.format("Lat:\t %f\nLong:\t %f\nAlt:\t %f\nBearing:\t %f", location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude(), location.getAltitude(),
                    location.getBearing());
            this.locationText.setText(text);  

                    try {     
                        List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 10); //<10> 
                        for (Address address : addresses) {    
                            this.locationText.append("\n" + address.getAddressLine(0));   
                            }          
                        int latitude = (int)(location.getLatitude() * 1000000);  
                        int longitude = (int)(location.getLongitude() * 1000000);  
                        GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(latitude,longitude);    
                        mapController.animateTo(point); //<11> 


                    }
                    catch (IOException e) {  
                        Log.e("LocateMe", "Could not get Geocoder data", e);   
                        }
//         
    }
                    @Override
                    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,Bundle extras) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                    }


//                  @Override  protected void onResume() { 
//                  LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener(){
//                        super.onResume(); 
//                  locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 10, this); //<7> 
//                  }  
//              @Override  protected void onPause() { 
//                  super.onPause();   
//                  locationManager.removeUpdates(this); //<8>
//                      
//                  }


//@Override
//protected void onResume() {
//    super.onResume();
//
//    // when our activity resumes, we want to register for location updates
//
//
//    myLocationOverlay.enableMyLocation();
//
//}
//
//@Override
//protected void onPause() {
//    super.onPause();
//
//    // when our activity pauses, we want to remove listening for location updates
//
//    myLocationOverlay.disableMyLocation();
//
//}



      @Override
        protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
           return false;

        }
}
```

Now the Itemized Overlay class:

```
public class HelloItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay {

    private ArrayList<OverlayItem> mOverlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
    private Context mContext;

    public HelloItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker) {
        super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
            }

    public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay) {
        mOverlays.add(overlay);
        populate();
    }

    @Override
    protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
        return mOverlays.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return mOverlays.size();
    }

//  @Override
//    protected boolean onTap(int index) {
//      AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MapConnect.instance);
//    switch (index) {
//            case 0:
//                Toast.makeText(MapConnect.instance, "GeoLocation : 0",
//                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//                dialog.show();
//            break;
//        }
//
//        return true;
//    }



    @Override
    protected boolean onTap(final int index) {

              final OverlayItem id = mOverlays.get(index);
              AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MapConnect.instance);
              dialog.setTitle("your title");
              dialog.setMessage("youmessage");
              //dialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
              dialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int index) {
                  dialog.dismiss();
                    }
              });
              dialog.show();
              return true;

              }




    }
```

This is the Logcat error i am getting:

```
2-06 07:17:34.822: E/InputEventReceiver(6112): Exception dispatching input event.
02-06 07:17:34.822: E/MessageQueue-JNI(6112): Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
02-06 07:17:34.893: E/MessageQueue-JNI(6112): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-06 07:17:34.893: E/MessageQueue-JNI(6112):   at android.app.AlertDialog.resolveDialogTheme(AlertDialog.java:143)
02-06 07:17:34.893: E/MessageQueue-JNI(6112):   at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.<init>(AlertDialog.java:360)
02-06 07:17:34.893: E/MessageQueue-JNI(6112):   at com.example.mapconnect.HelloItemizedOverlay.onTap(HelloItemizedOverlay.java:58)
02-06 07:17:34.893: E/MessageQueue-JNI(6112):   at com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay.onTap(ItemizedOverlay.java:453)
02-06 07:17:34.893: E/MessageQueue-JNI(6112):   at com.google.android.maps.OverlayBundle.onTap(OverlayBundle.java:83)
02-06 07:17:34.893: E/MessageQueue-JNI(6112):   at com.google.android.maps.MapView$1.onSingleTapUp(MapView.java:358)
02-06 07:17:34.893: E/MessageQueue-JNI(6112):   at com.google.android.maps.GestureDetector.onTouchEvent(GestureDetector.java:562)
02-06 07:17:34.893: E/MessageQueue-JNI(6112):   at com.google.android.maps.MapView.onTouchEvent(MapView.java:685)
02-06 07:17:34.893: E/MessageQueue-JNI(6112):   at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7239)
02-06 07:17:34.893: E/MessageQueue-JNI(6112):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2168)
02-06 07:17:34.893: E/MessageQueue-JNI(6112):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1903)
02-06 07:17:34.893: E/MessageQueue-JNI(6112):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
02-06 07:17:34.893: E/MessageQueue-JNI(6112):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
02-06 07:17:34.893: E/MessageQueue-JNI(6112):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
02-06 07:17:34.893: E/MessageQueue-JNI(6112):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
02-06 07:17:34.893: E/MessageQueue-JNI(6112):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
02-06 07:17:34.893: E/MessageQueue-JNI(6112):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
02-06 07:17:34.893: E/MessageQueue-JNI(6112):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
02-06 07:17:34.893: E/MessageQueue-JNI(6112):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
```

Comment: Look down the exception for the first line that references your code.  What's here?  `at com.example.mapconnect.HelloItemizedOverlay.onTap(HelloItemizedOverlay.java:58)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my answer as i made a silly mistake.I didn't initialize the context for main activity.After adding below in Oncreate, it worked. instance=MapConnect.this

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Instead of `null` empty value hope this will solve your problem

```
  OverlayItem overlayitem  = new OverlayItem(point1, "", "");
```

Comment: Hi Murali,I tried but it is still giving the same error. It must be something wrong in my Alertdialog creation in second class.

Comment: Hi,

I got my answer as i made a silly mistake.I didn't initialize the context for main activity.After adding below in Oncreate, it worked.

instance=MapConnect.this;